# Deleting a Secure Cookie in tornado

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I just started learning about webservers, tornado in particular.

I want to write a simple webpage with a login function.
As described in the [Tornado Documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#id1), I'm creating a secure cookie after the user was successfully loged-in:

```
self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("user"))
```

But how do I provide the user with a way to log-out?
As mentioned before, I'm not familiar with web servers, but as I'm checking this cookie when the user attempts to enter the Main-Page, I guess I'd just have to remove it after the user pressed "logout"?

Unfortunately, I could'nt find anything about this in the tornado documentatoin, nor on SO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could reset the cookie to an empty string via

```
self.clear_cookie("user")
```

Which would make the call to get_current_user return `False`. Take a look at the [blog demo](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/blog/blog.py) for an example (using OAuth, but still relevant).